# background color of angular-fontawesome icons not scalling

Tags: css, angular, font-awesome

Im using `angular-fontawesome`
and want to change the background color of an font-awesome `fa-icon`

```
 <fa-icon 
    class="vue-icon"
    [icon]="faVue"
    ></fa-icon>
```

I changed the color using the class attribute

```
.vue-icon {
    padding: 10px;
    background: #62dda4;
}
```

If I use the `size` attribute to make the icon bigger the bg is only half filled

```
 <fa-icon 
    class="vue-icon"
    [icon]="faVue" 
    size="6x"
    ></fa-icon>
```

[image: change background color]

what causes this behavior ?

so far I could not found a background property from the library

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try giving it a block property to contain it.

```
.vue-icon {
  display: inline-block; /* add this line*/
  padding: 10px;
  background: #62dda4;
}
```